# Load Testing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: load-testing, visualstudio

We currently use Visual Studio to drive load tests against our software, and I'm trying to determine where we can improve data collection.

The best reference I've been able to find is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms318550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Is this pretty comprehensive? We have a SQL backend that throws information to load balanced IIS servers and so I'm trying to see just how much drilling down I can do in Visual Studio before I go outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to getting a repository created for your load test executed?
If you are referring that then you can find the script at following location on you disk:

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE** by the name of **loadtestrepository**

run the script and you will get a separate DB created on the SQL Server.

If you are referring something else then please explain.

Comment: Not necessarily. I know that is part of what VS2012 offers, and is where all the data collection lives. What I'm interested in is seeing if there's any other pieces that VS can track. For example, can it store every web request fired during the load test? Can it fire every SQL command and index it by timestamp? That way I'd be able to drill into problem areas easier. As it is I'm having to do a lot of investigation after the load test is completed.

Comment: I don't think so that it can fire some queries while the load test is performed, rather u can trace the time taken to execute SQL queries/SPs using SQL tracing.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that. I was hoping there'd be a way to do it natively from within Visual Studio rather than setting up a few different ways of tracking things.

Comment: You can have it store all web requests/responses by adjusting the "Maximum Test Logs" and "Save Log Frequency for Completed Tests" fields in the load test properties.  For SQL commands, you would need to look into SQL Server Profiler and SQL Server Trace.  You can automatically get performance counters from SQL, but you won't have insight into specific SQL commands that were executed without setting up profiling/tracing, and after the tests are completed there is nothing native in VS Load Testing to parse those traces.